NativeWind v4+ not applying className styles to Expo components
After upgrading to NativeWind v4+ in my Expo project, I’ve encountered an issue where components imported from expo (like Image) are not applying styles from the className prop. Specifically:
This is not working:
import { Image } from “expo-image”;

<Image className=“border-2 border-red-500” source=“image.png” />

While this does work with React Native components:
import { Image } from “react-native”;

<Image className=“border-2 border-red-500” source=“image.png” />

It seems that any component imported from expo fails to pick up styles from className, while core React Native components work as expected.
Here’s my setup:
babel.config.js:
module.exports = function (api) {
api.cache(true);

return {
presets: [[‘babel-preset-expo’, { jsxImportSource: ‘nativewind’ }], ‘nativewind/babel’],
plugins: [‘react-native-reanimated/plugin’],
};
};

metro.config.js (for monorepo setup):
const path = require(‘node:path’);
const { getDefaultConfig } = require(’@expo/metro-config’);
const { withNativeWind } = require(‘nativewind/metro’);

const projectRoot = __dirname;
const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(projectRoot, ‘../..’);

const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot);

config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot];
config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [path.resolve(projectRoot, ‘node_modules’), path.resolve(workspaceRoot, ‘node_modules’)];

config.transformer = { …config.transformer, unstable_allowRequireContext: true };
config.transformer.minifierPath = require.resolve(‘metro-minify-terser’);

module.exports = config;

module.exports = withNativeWind(config, { input: ‘./src/styles/global.css’ });

./src/styles/global.css:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

I’ve tried clearing cache, simplifying the metro.config.js, and other troubleshooting steps, but nothing seems to work.
